# How can I test client side coffeescript/js using node with expresso/jasmine/<other>

Tags: testing, backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs

I have a web app where the client side stuff is written with coffeescript and loaded with require.js.

I would like to be able to isolate and test this stuff using a node based test runner such as expresso (although other suggestions are welcome) so that I can integrate the client side testing with our CI server - which is currently Team City.

Here's my directory set up:

```
.
├── coffee
│   ├── models
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── expresso
│   ├── spec
│   ├── tests
│   └── views
├── static
│   └── js
│       ├── lib
│       ├── models
│       ├── tests
│       └── views
```

These are hooked up using require.js like so:

```
deps = [
   "lib/backbone", "models/websocket_collection", "/static/js/lib/date.js"
]

define(deps, (Backbone, ws) ->
    # module code and exports here
```

And loaded into the browser like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="my_mod" src="/static/js/my_mod.js"></script>
```

In an idea world now I'd like to be able to have a test module that looks like:

```
{Model1, Model2} = require "models/some_module"

exports.test_a = ->
    assert.equal # etc etc
```

I have several problems (having not really used node server side except when I played with zombie.js)

1. How do I tell node where all of my plain javascript dependencies are (in static/js/lib) some of these are as downloaded, but backbone.js has been marked up with require.js define stuff like so

   ```
   define(function(require, exports, module) {
       (function(){
   ```
2. How do I actually run the tests? I've tried r.js (which as I understand it is supposed to be a bridge between browser side require and node's require)

the problem I'm getting is:

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

I've also tried to require("allplugins-require") which is the script I load browser side to collect all of my client code, but that seems to break node's require.

- Is anybody doing this?
- If you're not doing this how are you testing your code (bonus points for integration with CI)?
- Any alternatives to require.js for managing client side dependencies that might play a bit better on the server side?

I'd be very happy to hear alternative approaches that people are using.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a long time trying to get this to work and eventually gave up. I did get it working, by referencing all of my require.js dependencies in a global variable and using that for the node.js tests, but the design was so ugly that I felt that I had defeated the point.

My current approach is:

- write my JavaScript modules as CommonJS modules
- Use the [Jasmine BDD node integration](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) to test my modules server-side
- Use [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch/) to make the CommonJS modules work client-side

This is working well for me, with the following caveats:

- Client-side debugging is difficult because stitch concatenates all my scripts. I found that leaving out libraries like jQuery from the stitch configuration helped with this.
- I don't have any way to debug server-side. There is a [node.js debugger](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector) but it has not worked with the last few versions of node.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty good approach... In your earlier global variable solution how dod you get around define being undefined?

Answer (score 3):

The docs for running requirejs via r.js in node [are here](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html). In particular, r.js replaces node's require with its own. It can load node-only packages/modules that are installed via npm as long as the npm-installed modules are not visible to the require.js config.

The other caveat is that r.js needs to be a sibling file to the main.js, the top level app js file that is run in the node environment.

The latest code for r.js will support loading requirejs as a node module (as in require('requirejs') and that will give a better integration story. That change will be in the 0.26.0 release.

Comment: Thanks, one other thing I'm struggling with is how to run the tests under r.js? i.e. Where does r.js get injected into a command like this: "expresso ./tests"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a few days hacking and I've now got my client side code (some of it anyway) packaged as commonjs modules and tested with jasmine-node.

If anyone's interested I've forked jasmine-node to add outputting of an xml file that integrates with a CI server. This is working pretty well.

I'll report back after I get stitch up and running.

Here's my fork: https://github.com/boothead/jasmine-node